# Pact.io verification test failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, pact

My pact.io verification is failing and Im not sure why.

I have provided the error message, pact test file, and node.js express server which serves up the data below.

I am getting this error:

```
0) The following request was expected but not received:
        Method: GET
        Path: /dogs`enter code here`
```

Test Code:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const { Pact } = require("@pact-foundation/pact");

// Implementation of the function to be tested
function getMeDogs() {
  return axios
    .get("http://localhost:3000/dogs")
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error fetching dogs:", error.message);
      throw error;
    });
}

// Pact contract test
const provider = new Pact({
  port: 3000, // Use a free port here
  consumer: "Dog Consumer",
  provider: "Dog Provider",
});

provider
  .setup()
  .then(() => {
    provider.addInteraction({
      uponReceiving: "A request for all dogs",
      withRequest: {
        method: "GET",
        path: "/dogs",
      },
      willRespondWith: {
        status: 200,
        body: [
          { name: "Buddy", breed: "Labrador" },
          { name: "Max", breed: "German Shepherd" },
        ],
      },
    });
  })
  .then(() => {
    return getMeDogs(); // Call the function under test
  })
  .then((dogs) => {
    console.log(dogs);
  })
  .then(() => provider.verify())
  .finally(() => provider.finalize());
```

Server:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Hardcoded array of dogs
const dogs = [
  { name: "Buddy", breed: "Labrador" },
  { name: "Max", breed: "German Shepherd" },
];

// Route to fetch dogs
app.get("/dogs", (req, res) => {
  res.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
  res.status(200).json(dogs);
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Please give me some help! Thanks.
I have looked all over for an answer to just a simple pact contract test.  I finally found this one to work, mostly, but with the above stated error.